# Sub from submodule namespace does not execute from MAIN sub

Tags: module, namespaces, program-entry-point

look at this example:

```raku
unit module Mod;

module Mod::TestModule {
    our sub testSub { say "ok" }
}

sub MAIN { Mod::TestModule::testSub }
```

This does not print "ok", but it will work if change the last line to this:

```raku
Mod::TestModule::testSub
```

or to this:

```raku
sub testSub { Mod::TestModule::testSub }
testSub
```

#### Question

Why is this happening? What should I do, if I really want to use `MAIN`?